# Sharing deployment packages in SCCM

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012

I'm working on a SCCM server and I have a number of Automatic Deployment Rules that target different computers on specific schedules.

All of these ADRs use nearly identical selection parameters - number of requirements, update classification, etc all. They also update the same package and don't create new versions.

Would I be better served using a single deployment package *shared between all these tasks* or setting them up individually? If I go with individual sequences are there any tweaks I should put in place to avoid unnecessary network traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three years later.. Phased deployments are now a thing in the technical preview branch for SCCM.